# Querying sub document of sub document in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I wanted to save the data in "messageSchema" which is sub document of chatSchema by checking the "receiver" of chatSchema and "username" of userSchema.

like pseudoCode:-

```
if(userSchema.username == "Rahul" && userSchema.chatSchema.receiver){
then save the data in chatSchema.message;
}
```

Here is my Schema:-

```
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    messageId: {type: String, unique: true, required: true},
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    messageContent: String
});

var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    message: [messageSchema],
    receiver: {type: String, required: true}
});

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    token: { type: String, required: false },
    conversations: [chatSchema]
});
```

please suggest what should be code to save the message data.
tried below one that didn't work.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({username: "rahul", "conversations.receiver": data.receiver },{$push: {"conversations.message": message}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) instead of the dot notation for matching properties within an array. Try this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    username: "rahul",
    conversations: {
      $elemMatch: { receiver: data.receiver }
    }
  },
  // or whatever your update is
 {$push: {"conversations.message": message}
})
```

Comment: thanks @jakemingolla for the help, but i wanted to update it when "conversations" is not blank and wanted to push simply the object instead of "$elemMatch" in null case. Can you suggest on this.